# How do swing component's model can request redraw?

Tags: java, swing, model, onchange

I have my custom component which holds it's data in my custom data class. My component `extends JComponent` while data is fully custom.

What is conventional pattern a data class can notify component it was changed? Should I just implement some event inside data class and let component subscribe to it when data is set? Or there is predefined pattern is Swing library?

I am looking, for example, at `ListModel<E>` interface and see that is just has `addListDataListener(ListDataListener l)` and `removeListDataListener(ListDataListener l)`. Is this that mechanism model notifies `List`?

Answer (score 4):

For the record, this is mostly my personal opinion (since this is more of an opinion question).

Typically with a Swing application it's best to separate your code out into Model/View/Control (MVC).  This means that the actual Swing components are your Viow, your listeners are your Control, and your code that actually does stuff is the Model.  In this case both your View and Model only know about the Control (and the Control knows about both the View and Model).

So if your Model updates - it notifies the Control, which updates the View.  It's the same thing with the View (Listeners in the View execute, notifying the Control, which updates the Model).

The advantage of this is that it loosely couples the View and the Model (the view only cares about showing stuff to the user, and the model only cares about the data, and they don't care what each other are doing so long as they get the right information).

Here's an example (for simplicity they're all in one file, but usually you'd have the MVC each in their own file at the very least):

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MVCSeparation {

    // Model:  (Number crunching math-y) or (data processing) stuff
    public static class Model{
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        public void addData(String value){
            data.add(value);
        }

        public int getCount(){
            return data.size();
        }

        public String randomValue(){
            String result = "";
            if(data.size() > 0){
                int index = (int)(Math.random() * data.size());
                System.out.println(index);
                result = data.get(index);
            }
            System.out.println("Getting Value: " + result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    // View:  Pretty graphics and visuals
    public static class View extends Box{
        JLabel text = new JLabel("Random Value:");
        JTextField newItem = new JTextField(10);
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");

        public View(){
            super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
            add(text);
            add(newItem);
            add(submit);
        }

        public void setSubmitAction(ActionListener submitAction){
            submit.addActionListener(submitAction);
        }

        public void setDisplayText(String value){
            text.setText("Random Value: " + value);
        }

        public String getText(){
            String result = newItem.getText();
            newItem.setText("");
            return result;
        }

        public void startupApp(){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setContentPane(this);
            frame.validate();
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    // Processing User Interactions and Data Updates (links two above together)
    public static class Control{
        Model m = new Model();
        View v = new View();

        public Control(){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    v.setSubmitAction(new SubmitText());
                    v.startupApp();
                }});

            //Randomly update label
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        v.setDisplayText(m.randomValue());
                    }});
            }
        }

        // Listener to notify us of user interactions on the View
        public class SubmitText implements ActionListener{
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m.addData(v.getText());
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Control();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Observable` or `PropertyChangeListener`.